unable to see data/chart in cloudwatch for already terminated instance in AWS
Why I am unable to see data/chart for CPU Utilization Metrics  in cloudwatch for already terminated instance ?
On other hand I can still see data/chart for Memory utilization.

You should be able to see it. Have another look around cloudwatch, sometimes it can be a bit fiddly.

I understood, that  CPU Utilization Metrics is connected to Instance ID, so when you terminate, chart/data is gone.
Workaround is create cloudwatch dashboard  chart based on ASG groups, then you can see data.
